# install an old version application on an old device

Tags: android, google-play, telegram, messenger

I have an old Android rooted device with gingerbread 2.3.6 which has restored to factory defaults.

every time i restore my device to defaults, I have problem with installing telegram messenger . I can not exactly remember by which trick, I succeed downloading and installing old version of telegram from google play store after last "reset to factory". device only accepts installation from google play store only and all unofficial apks had received "not installed" error even with enabling "trust to unknown resource".

I think that in previous times and after updating device and installing google services, google play might automatically redirected me to suitable version of telegram for my devices(3.9.1 ).

is is possible to obtain direct link of download telegram 3.9.1 (current version is 4.x.x) from google play?

Comment: You can download v 3.9.1 of telegram from here: https://telegram.en.uptodown.com/android/download/547735

Answer (score 0):

Even you obtain the direct link from Google Play, you have to download apk and install without Play Store.

A safe way to obtain APK is [APK Mirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/telegram-messenger-llp/telegram/telegram-3-9-1-release/), you can download `v3.9.1` from [here](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/telegram-messenger-llp/telegram/telegram-3-9-1-release/telegram-3-9-1-android-apk-download/download/).